# How to make trivial changes to code with significant effects when the original violates a current rule?

Tags: support, bug

I wanted to edit [one of the answers](Http://stackoverflow.com/a/15176075/603977) to a question but a fight between HTML requirements and the code display requirements made it impossible to do this, despite attempting increasingly heavy-handed measures to accomplish what could have been extremely easy. I'm here to find out if what I want to do could be done.

The higher-rated of the two answers has two features of interest:

1. A display of sample code containing an item in angle brackets, copied and modified from the question.
2. A <s>struck-out</s> line within the display of sample code, to emphasize that a line of code needs to be deleted.

The answer does not format the code display using 4 indenting spaces. Instead it uses <pre><code> directly. But there is a string <INSTALL-DIR> in the code sample which is inadvertently invisible because it looks like an undefined HTML open or void tag. I believe **numerous** editors have tried to fix this problem unsuccessfully, but there is no record of their attempts. There is no record of their attempts because there is no way to submit an attempt. I tried three times.

My first attempt at a fix was to change as few characters as possible. I tried to change the "<" at the beginning of "<INSTALL-DIR>" to "&lt;" and I submitted that. That change was rejected because it didn't meet the minimum number of changed characters.

My second attempt at a fix was to change the errant string at both ends. I changed the "<" and the ">" to their corresponding HTML entities. That attempt failed because "You can't submit code using <pre>" During my edits there was a scary red box adjacent to the editing widget that said I should indent "my" code using 4 spaces. The error message I got upon submitting my second attempt specifically called my attention to that red box.

I aborted my third attempt without submitting, because the preview showed that there was nothing I could do to preserve the struck-out line in context. To wit, I removed the <pre><code> sequence and its complementary ending sequence and indented the block with 4 spaces. Unfortunately that left the struck-out section with its tags in view instead of the tags striking out the line. I couldn't find a way to format the line as struck-out.

How could this answer be edited successfully? How could the edit be accomplished without running rampant over the original text?

Tagged with bug because I could not do what I set out to do even though I tried three ways to do it. I strongly doubt that Markdown is going to allow strike-outs in indented code.

Comment: Fixed ... by using `&gt;` and `&gt;` in the same edit ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I did that very thing, &lt;INSTALL_DIR&gt; as my second attempt. The failure of that attempt was supposedly due to not formatting code in the approved way.

Comment: @DavidPostill: you're not subject to the 6-character minimum anyways, having the editing privilege. It's only suggested edits that face that limitation.

Comment: @JoshCaswell; That seems like it could be the answer: E.g. Cardiff space man, you need to earn more rep before you can make such a small edit.